# Issue with wildcard certificate on asp.net core using Http.sys and service fabric

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl-certificate, azure-service-fabric

I have been running a dev and test Service Fabric cluster using self signed ssl certificates under http.sys listener type with no issues. Now that I am preparing to go to production I created a real SSL cert from DigiCert as a wildcard cert with a number of Subject Alternative Names. However, when trying to bring this up when running locally to verify the configuration, it fails and the diagnostic information reports

```
"Cannot find the certificate and private key to use for decryption".
```

Issuing a:

```
netsh http show sslcert
```

shows that it is properly registering the cert

```
    IP:port                      : 0.0.0.0:8113
    Certificate Hash             : 9e324673476570cc51a8dff7789f6cf8436cec38
    Application ID               : {c5f2a686-3b30-4490-b86e-cb88b15fd92b}
    Certificate Store Name       : My
    Verify Client Certificate Revocation : Disabled
    Verify Revocation Using Cached Client Certificate Only : Disabled
    Usage Check                  : Enabled
    Revocation Freshness Time    : 0
    URL Retrieval Timeout        : 0
    Ctl Identifier               : (null)
    Ctl Store Name               : (null)
    DS Mapper Usage              : Disabled
    Negotiate Client Certificate : Disabled
    Reject Connections           : Disabled
    Disable HTTP2                : Not Set
    Disable QUIC                 : Not Set
    Disable TLS1.3               : Not Set
    Disable OCSP Stapling        : Not Set
```

with the thumbprint I am telling it to use(9e324673476570cc51a8dff7789f6cf8436cec38) in the EndpointCertificate element in ApplicationManifest.xml.  The cert is valid with valid keys. the only difference between this cert and the self signed dev/test one is the Subject and Subject Alternative Name attribute. The dev/test one has a dummy domain like dev.sample.com but the real one is *.myrealdomain.com.

Any idea why it throws this error when clearly a valid cert by that thumbprint exists and is getting registered with netsh properly?

In addition, this same cert is used as the cluster certificate placed in Azure Key Vault and works fine there and is used for another domain under an app service without issue.

Comment: Did you properly set the ACL's for the certificate? https://github.com/Azure/Service-Fabric-Troubleshooting-Guides/blob/master/Security/Set%20ACL%20for%20a%20SF%20certificate.md

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out the issue and it was not actually related to the SSL cert.  After narrowing things down and isolating the issue, I found that I had a parameter that was encrypted that needed to be encrypted with my new encryption cert(SecretsCertificate).  The error message was misleading. What it should have said was...

```
"Cannot find the certificate and private key to use for decryption of an encrypted Parameter"
```

Note to anyone out there using SecretsCertificate. If you switch your cert between different environments, make sure ALL encypted settings in your manifest/cloud/local xml files have been encrypted with the cert you refer to with a thumbprint in SecretsCertificate.